# How to write a method that accepts an int and returns a Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a method eMinus but I have been getting a lot of errors. Bellow is my code. I would greatly appreciate some advice.

Write a method eMinus that accepts an int index as a parameter and returns an Employee array. The returned array should be one element smaller than e and without the element at index index. The elements in the returned array should otherwise maintain the same order as in e. To delete an element at index index, use: e = eMinus(index);

```
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      public class Controller2 {

    //Data Members   
      Employee2 [] e = new Employee2 [0]; 
      int counter = 0; //int variable = counter
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Method eMinus 
        int[] eMinus (int index, Employee2 [] e) {
            int [] Employee3 = new int [e.length - 1 ];
            for (int loop = 0 ; loop < index; loop++)
                Employee3[loop] = e[loop];
            for (int loop = index + 1; loop < e.length; loop++)
                Employee3[loop-1]=Employee2[loop];
            return Employee3;//employee array 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eMinus looks like it should almost work, except you're creating and returning an array of integers (called Employee3) instead of an array of Employee2s..

```
Employee2[] eMinus(int index, Employee2[] input) {
     Employee2[] result = new Employee2[input.length - 1];
     for (int i = 0 ; i < index; i++)
         result[i] = input[i];
     for (int i = index + 1; i < input.length; i++)
         result[i - 1] = input[i];
     return result;
}
```

The names you used suggest that you might be somewhat confused about types, arrays and variables.. Try reading on what the distinction is, and whether you need to have Employee, Employee2 and Employee3 or not (it's likely that the answer is no).

Comment: Yes, I did not need and Employee or Employee.

Answer (score 0):

> To delete an element at index index, use: e = eMinus(index);

does that mean that you're not passing array to your eMinus method but dealing with instance variable?.

Though, I can't find any reason to use arrays if you know that you'll be modifying it (there are much more suitable data structures to deal with in your case), I would do something like this:

```
Employee2[] empls = new Employee2 [0]; // btw, why are you creating an empty array here?

Employee2[] eMinus(int index) throws Exception {
    if (empls == null) {
        // return an empty array or some valid exception
        // or whatever you want to deal with this situation   
    }
    if (index < 0 || index > empls.length-1) {
        // return an empty array or some valid exception
        // or whatever you want to deal with this situation
    }

    Employee2[] result = new Employee2[empls.length - 1];
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < empls.length; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            result[c++] = empls[i];
        }
    }

    return new result;
}
```